# How to handle Datagrid column's events from Presenter?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2, gwt-mvp

I am using [GWT MVP](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) and I would like to handle events in columns of [DataGrid](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) from Presenter.
From [GWT DataGrid ShowCase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) ...

```
    // First name.
Column<ContactInfo, String> firstNameColumn =
    new Column<ContactInfo, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
      @Override
      public String getValue(ContactInfo object) {
        return object.getFirstName();
      }
    };
firstNameColumn.setSortable(true);
sortHandler.setComparator(firstNameColumn, new Comparator<ContactInfo>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(ContactInfo o1, ContactInfo o2) {
    return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
  }
});
dataGrid.addColumn(firstNameColumn, constants.cwDataGridColumnFirstName());
firstNameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ContactInfo, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, ContactInfo object, String value) {
    // Here I would like to call RPC methods
  }
});
dataGrid.setColumnWidth(firstNameColumn, 20, Unit.PCT);
```

Above example , this code is writing in [View](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html#view) side and it just really example. As mvp pattern , I just need to call rpc request to update database. This can't be done in [View](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html#view) side but I have no idea how to set [FieldUpdater](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/FieldUpdater.html) from my presenter. Please help me how can I figure it out ? Thanks greatly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this (MVP I or MVP II way):

### MVP 1 style:

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html

Create a `setter` on your `View` (i.e. `setFieldUpdater(FieldUpdater<ContactInfo, String>)`) that takes a `FieldUpdater` and adds it to the column. From the `Presenter` you can call (provided that `view` is the reference to your View).

**Presenter**:

```
view.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ContactInfo, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, ContactInfo object, String value) {
    // Make the RPC call
  }
});
```

### MVP2 style:

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html

If you have a reference from your `View` back to your `Presenter`. Then you can call a function on your `Presenter`.

**View**:

```
firstNameColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ContactInfo, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(int index, ContactInfo object, String value) {
    getPresenter().onUpdate(info,value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Ümit , Now I got it. Thanks for mvp-architecture-2 , I know only about mvp-architecture-1 before. Now I can add or control handlers of data grid from presenter. Thanks for perfect answer.

Comment: Sure np, I would actually recommend to take the MVP-II approach as it makes testing easier and cleaner.